# Like não retorna dados

Tags: java, android, sql

Tenho uma função no mysql que retorna um valor decimal. Nessa função tem um like. Quando testo o sql no **mysql** o valor é retornado caso insiro uma letra ou mais de uma. Ex: LIKE 'Casa%'. Quanto ao sql que está num **método de uma classe** no servidor Tomcat, ao ser inserido uma letra num editText de um app Android o dados são retornados, "mas se inserir **mais de uma letra**, o dado retornado é 0.00, ou seja, é null", correspondente a linha da função no mysql: ifnull(sum(cp.valorContaPaga), 0.00) as v into valor. Detalhe, testando no navegador também retorna 0.00. Pergunto: Porque está retornando null na classe java enquanto no teste no mysql retorna o valor? Aguardo, obrigado.

Segue a função:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `somaContaNomeMesAno`(conta varchar(20), 
data varchar(10)) RETURNS double(8,2)
BEGIN
DECLARE valor double(8,2);

select ifnull(sum(cp.valorContaPaga), 0.00) as v into valor
from contaFixa cf, contapagar cp 
where
cf.contaFixa like (insert('%%', 1, 1, conta)) -- funfando assim hehehe...
and month(cp.dataContaPaga) = month(data)
and year(cp.dataContaPaga) = year(data) 
and cf.idContaFixa = cp.idContaFixa;    

return valor;  

END;
```

Tabela contafixa:

```
IdContaFixa int(11)
contaFixa varchar(20)
dataContaFixa date
valorContaFixa double(6,2)
qtddParcela char(3)
```

Tabela contapagar:

```
idContaPagar int(11)
idContaFixa int(11)
dataVencimento date
valorContaPagar double(6,2)
dataContaPagar date
parcela tinyint(3)
```

ClassDao:

```
package br.com.restfull.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import br.com.restfull.factory.ConnectionFactory;
import br.com.restfull.model.ContaPagar;

public class ContaPagarDAO {    

private Connection connection;
private static ContaPagarDAO instance;
static NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
static SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

public static ContaPagarDAO getIsntance(){

    if(instance == null){
        instance = new ContaPagarDAO();         
    }
    return instance;        
}

public ContaPagarDAO(){
    this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
}

public ContaPagarDAO(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
}

public ArrayList<ContaPagar> getListNomeContaPagaMesAno(String conta,String dataPagamento) 
        throws ParseException {

    String SQL =  "select cp.idContaPagar, cp.idContaFixa, cf.contaFixa, cp.dataVencimento, "
                + "cp.valorContaPaga, cp.dataContaPaga, cp.parcela, cf.qtddParcela, "
                // Aqui está o problema, buahahahaha...  !!!
                + "somaContaNomeMesAno(?,?) as 'Soma' " // <-----
                + "from contaFixa cf, contapagar cp "                   
                + "where "
                // like (?\"%\") <-- Vai ajudar muita gente hehehe...
                + "cf.contafixa like (?\"%\") " 
                + "and month(cp.dataContaPaga) = month(?) "
                + "and year(cp.dataContaPaga) = year(?) " 
                + "and cf.idContaFixa = cp.idContaFixa "
                + "order by cf.contaFixa, cp.dataContaPaga";

    try {
        ArrayList<ContaPagar> contas = new ArrayList<ContaPagar>();
        PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement(SQL); 
        stmt.setString(1, conta);
// No banco o tipo é date, mas na classModel usei String... ué, q q tem?
        stmt.setString(2, dataPagamento); 
        stmt.setString(3, conta);
        stmt.setString(4, dataPagamento); 
        stmt.setString(5, dataPagamento);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            ContaPagar contaPaga = new ContaPagar();     
            contaPaga.setIdContaPagar(rs.getLong("idContaPagar"));           
            contaPaga.setIdContaFixa(rs.getLong("idContaFixa"));
            contaPaga.setContaFixa(rs.getString("contaFixa")); 
            contaPaga.setDataVencimento(convertMapedToSqlFormat(rs.getDate("dataVencimento")));
            contaPaga.setValorContaPaga(convertValor(rs.getString("valorContaPaga")).toString());
            contaPaga.setDataContaPaga(convertMapedToSqlFormat(rs.getDate("dataContaPaga")));
            contaPaga.setParcela(rs.getShort("parcela"));
            contaPaga.setQtddParcela(rs.getShort("qtddParcela"));
            contaPaga.setSomaContaNomeMesAno(convertValor(rs.getString("Soma"))); // alias

            contas.add(contaPaga);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        return contas;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/* 
* Converte para dd/MM/yyyy e contorna o problema do escape... blz !!!
* Pois estava dando pau no navegador...
* ... esses espaços entre as palavras nos deixam louUUucosss....
*/
public static String convertMapedToSqlFormat(Date date2) throws  ParseException { 
    Date date = date2; 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cal.setTime(date); 

    return dbDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
}   

// Retorna formato Monetário
public static String convertValor(String valorServico){         
    String valorConvert = valorServico;     
    Double d = Double.valueOf(valorConvert);        
    return nf.format(d);
}
}
```

ClassModel:

```
package br.com.restfull.model;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@XmlRootElement
public class ContaPagar implements Serializable{

private Long idContaPagar;
private Long idContaFixa;
private String contaFixa;
private String dataVencimento;
private String valorContaPaga; // No banco o tipo é double... e daí?!!  hehehe...
private String dataContaPaga;
private Short parcela;
private Short qtddParcela;
private Byte pago;
private String somaMesAno;
private String somaDia;
private String somaValorMesAno;
private String somaValorDia;
private String somaContaNomeMesAno;
private String somaContaNomeDia;    

public Long getIdContaPagar() {
    return idContaPagar;
}
public void setIdContaPagar(Long idContaPagar) {
    this.idContaPagar = idContaPagar;
}
public Long getIdContaFixa() {
    return idContaFixa;
}
public void setIdContaFixa(Long idContaFixa) {
    this.idContaFixa = idContaFixa;
}   
public String getContaFixa() {
    return contaFixa;
}
public void setContaFixa(String contaFixa) {
    this.contaFixa = contaFixa;
}
public String getDataVencimento() {
    return dataVencimento;
}
public void setDataVencimento(String dataVencimento) {
    this.dataVencimento = dataVencimento;
}
public String getValorContaPaga() {
    return valorContaPaga;
}
public void setValorContaPaga(String valorContaPaga) {
    this.valorContaPaga = valorContaPaga;
}
public String getDataContaPaga() {
    return dataContaPaga;
}
public void setDataContaPaga(String dataContaPaga) {
    this.dataContaPaga = dataContaPaga;
}
public Byte getPago() {
    return pago;
}
public void setPago(Byte pago) {
    this.pago = pago;
}   
public Short getParcela() {
    return parcela;
}
public void setParcela(Short parcela) {
    this.parcela = parcela;
}
public Short getQtddParcela() {
    return qtddParcela;
}
public void setQtddParcela(Short qtddParcela) {
    this.qtddParcela = qtddParcela;
}   
public String getSomaMesAno() {
    return somaMesAno;
}
public void setSomaMesAno(String somaMesAno) {
    this.somaMesAno = somaMesAno;
}
public String getSomaDia() {
    return somaDia;
}
public void setSomaDia(String somaDia) {
    this.somaDia = somaDia;
}
public String getSomaValorMesAno() {
    return somaValorMesAno;
}
public void setSomaValorMesAno(String somaValorMesAno) {
    this.somaValorMesAno = somaValorMesAno;
}
public String getSomaValorDia() {
    return somaValorDia;
}
public void setSomaValorDia(String somaValorDia) {
    this.somaValorDia = somaValorDia;
}   
public String getSomaContaNomeMesAno() {
    return somaContaNomeMesAno;
}
public void setSomaContaNomeMesAno(String somaContaNomeMesAno) {
    this.somaContaNomeMesAno = somaContaNomeMesAno;
}
public String getSomaContaNomeDia() {
    return somaContaNomeDia;
}
public void setSomaContaNomeDia(String somaContaNomeDia) {
    this.somaContaNomeDia = somaContaNomeDia;
}

public String toString(){

    return this.idContaPagar + 
            this.idContaFixa + 
            this.contaFixa + 
            this.dataVencimento + 
            this.valorContaPaga + 
            this.dataContaPaga + 
            this.pago;
}   

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((contaFixa == null) ? 0 : contaFixa.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((dataContaPaga == null) ? 0 : dataContaPaga.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((dataVencimento == null) ? 0 : dataVencimento.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((idContaFixa == null) ? 0 : idContaFixa.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((idContaPagar == null) ? 0 : idContaPagar.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((pago == null) ? 0 : pago.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((parcela == null) ? 0 : parcela.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((qtddParcela == null) ? 0 : qtddParcela.hashCode());
    result = prime
            * result
            + ((somaContaNomeDia == null) ? 0 : somaContaNomeDia.hashCode());
    result = prime
            * result
            + ((somaContaNomeMesAno == null) ? 0 : somaContaNomeMesAno
                    .hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((somaDia == null) ? 0 : somaDia.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((somaMesAno == null) ? 0 : somaMesAno.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((somaValorDia == null) ? 0 : somaValorDia.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((somaValorMesAno == null) ? 0 : somaValorMesAno.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((valorContaPaga == null) ? 0 : valorContaPaga.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ContaPagar other = (ContaPagar) obj;
    if (contaFixa == null) {
        if (other.contaFixa != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!contaFixa.equals(other.contaFixa))
        return false;
    if (dataContaPaga == null) {
        if (other.dataContaPaga != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!dataContaPaga.equals(other.dataContaPaga))
        return false;
    if (dataVencimento == null) {
        if (other.dataVencimento != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!dataVencimento.equals(other.dataVencimento))
        return false;
    if (idContaFixa == null) {
        if (other.idContaFixa != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!idContaFixa.equals(other.idContaFixa))
        return false;
    if (idContaPagar == null) {
        if (other.idContaPagar != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!idContaPagar.equals(other.idContaPagar))
        return false;
    if (pago == null) {
        if (other.pago != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!pago.equals(other.pago))
        return false;
    if (parcela == null) {
        if (other.parcela != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!parcela.equals(other.parcela))
        return false;
    if (qtddParcela == null) {
        if (other.qtddParcela != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!qtddParcela.equals(other.qtddParcela))
        return false;
    if (somaContaNomeDia == null) {
        if (other.somaContaNomeDia != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaContaNomeDia.equals(other.somaContaNomeDia))
        return false;
    if (somaContaNomeMesAno == null) {
        if (other.somaContaNomeMesAno != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaContaNomeMesAno.equals(other.somaContaNomeMesAno))
        return false;
    if (somaDia == null) {
        if (other.somaDia != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaDia.equals(other.somaDia))
        return false;
    if (somaMesAno == null) {
        if (other.somaMesAno != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaMesAno.equals(other.somaMesAno))
        return false;
    if (somaValorDia == null) {
        if (other.somaValorDia != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaValorDia.equals(other.somaValorDia))
        return false;
    if (somaValorMesAno == null) {
        if (other.somaValorMesAno != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!somaValorMesAno.equals(other.somaValorMesAno))
        return false;
    if (valorContaPaga == null) {
        if (other.valorContaPaga != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!valorContaPaga.equals(other.valorContaPaga))
        return false;
    return true;
}   
}
```

Class ConnectionFactory

```
package br.com.restfull.factory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

/**
 * Classe responsável pela 
 * <br>Conexão com o db. 
 * @author ovoFrito
 * @since 05/07/2014
 * É isso aí... Trabalhando um ano e três meses nesse app!!!
 * @version 1.0 
 * */
public class ConnectionFactory {

public Connection getConnection(){
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());   
        return DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx"); // hehehe...
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

 public void closeConnection(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
     try {
         close(conn, stmt, rs);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Falha ao fechar conexao.");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

public void closeConnection(Connection conn, Statement stmt) {
     try {
         close(conn, stmt, null);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Falha ao fechar conexao.");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

private void close(Connection conn, Statement stmt, ResultSet rs) {

     try {
         if (rs != null) {
             rs.close();
         }
         if (stmt != null) {
             stmt.close();
         }
         if (conn != null) {
             conn.close();
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Falha ao fechar conexao.");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }   
}
```

Se faltou algo me avisem! Obrigado.

Comment: Ative a opção de printar a query gerada no hibernate e compartilhe se possível.

Comment: Quando utilizar `like`na sql, procure deixar todos os caracteres no mesmo tipo.
Tente algo como isso.
`UPPER( campo ) like UPPER('?%') `

Comment: Esse é o sql usado, ou um exemplo? Pq se for o usado e vc tentar comparar uma palavra com uma data, acho mei dificil retorna alguma coisa...

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo,IIario e Gustavo. IIario, UPPER não não alterou o algorítimo. Gustavo, era só um exemplo, desculpa aê... hehehe... Atendendo ao conselho do Ricardo, postei mais informações. Vamos tentar descobrir o que ocorre? Já sabemos que o problema não está no navegador e também não está no Android. Parece que está no sql do método **getListNomeContaPagaMesAno**, justamente na linha  **somaContaNomeMesAno(?,?) as 'Soma' **. Só falta isso para terminar esse app aqui :( , acredito que mais pessoas tb estão com esse problema. Valeu....

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido!**
Um colega me indicou na função mysql o seguinte:

```
cf.contaFixa like (insert('%%', 1, 1, conta))
```

Realmente funcionou, mas **somente** no teste no mysql, na busca pelo método java só retorna valor se for inserido **apenas** uma letra, **mais de uma** letra retorna 0.00, ou seja null. Estudei um pouco mais o mysql e usei na função isso:

```
cf.contaFixa like concat('', conta,'%')
```

Embora o problema original esteja na sintaxe mysql e foi **resolvido** vou continuar pesquisando, porque no java apresentou problema em relação ao **insert** da função mysql. Desculpe-me as brincadeiras nos comentários, foi só para quebrar o extresse. Agradeço a todos e ao pt.stackoverflow.